# Bootcamp - Apple SPI Device driver missing - Touchpad/Keyboard don't work

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, windows, bootcamp, trackpad

I recently did a clean install of MacOS Big Sur on my 2016 MacBook Pro touchbar and did a Bootcamp install of the latest windows 10 pro.

During the install the keyboard and touchpad did not work, so I used an old usb mouse and the on-screen keyboard to get through. After booting into windows and installing the Bootcamp windows support software, connecting to the internet, downloading updates, etc..**the keyboard and touchpad still do not work in windows.**

In Device Manager > Other Devices I see 5 listings for `Apple SPI Device` with exclamation marks because it couldn't find a driver.

The frustrating thing is that my setup was working perfectly in both MacOS and Windows a few days ago.

Any ideas? How can I install the drivers for those `Apple SPI Devices`?

Comment: Did you use the Boot Camp Assistant to remove, then install the current release of Windows 10? Or, did you use a different method?

Comment: When downloading updates, did you check to see if Windows Update offered any optional driver updates? Did you run the Apple Software Update application to see if Apple offered any updates?

Comment: Yes, I used boot camp assistant to remove and reinstall the current windows installation. And yes, I installed the few apple updates (Boot Camp 6.1) as well as all the necessary and optional windows updates...

Comment: I asked because user Will Haley posted a [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/419300/boot-camp-error) 6 days ago where using the Boot Camp Assistant was the solution for a Mac model similar to yours.

Comment: @DavidAnderson close, but not quite! Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some more messing around (and a bunch of trial-and-error) I was able to identify and manually install the keyboard and trackpad drivers!

**To manually install the keyboard and trackpad drivers to their respective SPI Device entries in Device Manager, I clicked 'Update Driver'>'Browse my computer...'>'Let me pick from a list...'>'Human Interface Devices'>'Apple Inc.'>Apple SPI Keyboard/Trackpad'**

On my 2016 MacBookPro touch bar, this is how the Apple SPI Devices correlated to the drivers, based on the value in Properties>Details>Property: Hardware Ids:

```
SPI\VID_05ac&PID_027b&MI_01 (SPI Bus Location 1) - Apple SPI Keyboard

SPI\VID_05ac&PID_027b&MI_02 (SPI Bus Location 2) - Apple SPI Trackpad
```

However, I still need to determine which drivers go with the remaining 3 unknown devices. Their hardware IDs are:

```
SPI\VID_05ac&PID_027b&MI_00 (SPI Bus Location 0)

SPI\VID_05ac&PID_027b&MI_03 (SPI Bus Location 3)

SPI\VID_05ac&PID_027b&MI_04 (SPI Bus Location 4)
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what these 3 hardware devices are?

Comment: worked on my late 2017 MBP. I wonder why this happened - my previous Bootcamp installation was fine. Maybe that was with Windows 7.

Would be nice if someone with working drivers would post those remaining three SPI devices.